# Is there a way of hiding your server credentials in js

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am writing a game in JavaScript, and it is designed to save data to a firebase. However, in order to stop people from giving themselves infinite money, I wrapped my whole program in an anonymous function so they couldn't access their player values.

This works well, but somebody could just copy the whole of my script and make changes anywhere they like in the firebase, be it their user data or somebody else's. I need a way of preventing people from seeing my credentials to pass into the firebase app. I have thought about deleting the file as soon as it starts to execute, but am unsure how to do this and if it will stop execution etc.

NB: I am using firebase real-time database, *not* the cloud firestore.

Comment: You need server side software.

Comment: You can use firebase rules to allow operations to only requests from your web page address as referrer.

Comment: Once you deliver code to be executed in the user's browser, you should consider it compromised, and modifiable by an attacker.  All secure operations should be done on a backend with strict controls.

Comment: Yes, but if i use the firebase rules somebody can go in to the chrome console and copy and paste, it would be registered as from my domain